# How can I run php file by just double clicking it

Tags: php

I have installed xampp and created a simple hello word php file in the htdocs folder... Then i set default application to run php files as google chrome... Now, when I double click the first.php file, chrome opens with the following address :

> file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/first.php

Now this shows the code which i have written... It should open as

> localhost/first.php

when i double click it so as to show the output. I can manually change it but can i set it to open like that on default... How to change this?

Comment: No u simply can't... Localhost is the ip address of your server 127.0.0.1  ..this isn't html page to open directly... Better way u use browser and add a bookmark of it :)

Comment: you *could* write your own little program as custom handler that takes the filename of a PHP-script as input argument, maps it to the corresponding localhost-URL and then opens the browser with that url. although that definitely wouldn't be a very *clean* way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you double click the file, its basically open with the absolute path of file location in browser, as the path is absolute, so the server which reply the response of your query is the file management server of your system, which simply open the file.
But if you open with link
`localhost/first.php`, its basically send the request to the http server of your system which parse the file and send back the content which browser knows, this browser show you the desired result
If you want to open that file by double click, you can do one thing, create a new file `open.html` in which you can write the code for redirection

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://localhost/first.php" />
```